# Magma location

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Is there a way to know where the magma pool is (that preferably doesn't involve mining in random directions)? If not, does magma usually exist on a certain depth or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two sources of guaranteed lava in Dwarf Fortress -- The first is volcanoes. Embarking on a volcano will guarantee a ready source of lava.

The second happens during world gen when you allow / deny the existence of the magma sea (default is on). On worlds with a magma sea, you will hit magma as long as you keep digging down, past the third cavern level.

Comment: How deep in z-levels does that usually end up being?

Comment: @Andronikus - it varies highly depending on the elevation of your embark site. Mountains can place the magma sea at 100 z levels or greater, embarking in a swamp can get you in the low 30's.

Comment: Hmm yeah, that makes sense, what with the whole "realistic geology" business.  Thanks!